# Rails 3 uniqueness validation with scope on polymorphic table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, unique

I've got the following setup:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voteable, :polymorphic => :true, :counter_cache => true
end

class Proposition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, :as => :voteable
end

class Winner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, :as => :voteable
end
```

The Vote table looks like this:

```
t.string   "ip_address"
t.integer  "voteable_id"
t.string   "voteable_type"
```

I want to validate the following. A user with a given ip_address can only vote on 1 proposition. So the combination of ip_address, voteable_id and voteable_type needs to be unique.

How can i achieve this with a "simple" validation rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To guarantee uniqueness you have to add unique index to your DB

If you don't have important data yet you can do it inside migration with [add_index](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index)

```
add_index(:votes, [:ip_address, :voteable_id, voteable_type], :unique => true, :name => 'allowed_one_vote')
```

in case you already have some data it can be done with SQL and it depends on your DBMS

Comment: it's up to you if performance is fine you might leave it as it is

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The questioner wanted a validation. If there really is no specific validation for this situation, the answer is to just do a custom validation.  That may or may not be the "best" way (which depends on the situation), but doing a DB constraint vs a validation is apples and oranges.

Answer (score 3):

Add a scope to a unique `:ip_address` validation

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  validates :ip_address, uniqueness: { scope: [:voteable_type, :voteable_id]}
end
```